# Simple Visitor pattern malfunctioning

Tags: c++, oop, class, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I'm creating a very simple example of Visitor use. I've got a class Aerial, which has two methods of creating an array, methodA and methodB. However, even before I define those methods, the compiler gives out some illogical errors: `syntax error: identifier Aerial` and `"Visitor::VisitA : function does not take 1 arguments"`.

I've bundled the definition and declarations together to make the whole program simpler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

class Visitor
{
public:
     ~Visitor(){}
     void visitA(Aerial*){};
     void visitB(Aerial*){};
protected:
    Visitor(){}
};

class Aerial
{
private:
    double height, radius;
    double arr[MAX_SIZE];
protected:
    Aerial();
public:
    virtual ~Aerial(){};
    virtual void accept(Visitor&)=0;
};

class AerialA:public Aerial
{
public:
    void accept(Visitor &v)
    {
        v.visitA(this);
    }
};

class AerialB:public Aerial
{
public:
    void accept(Visitor &v)
    {
        v.visitB(this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to use forward declaration. Put

```
class Aerial;
```

before declaration of class `Visitor`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a forward declaration of `Aerial` before your `Visitor` class:

```
class Aerial;

//rest of your code.
```

This because you're using `Aerial` in your `Visitor` class.